# Update headerView in the didUpdateLocation

Tags: ios, uitableview

Hi guys I have the following code:

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    static NSString *LocationHeaderCellIdentifier = @"Location Header Cell";

    LocationHeaderCell *locationHeaderCell;
    locationHeaderCell = (LocationHeaderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LocationHeaderCellIdentifier];
    locationHeaderCell.lblCurrentAddress.text = self.currentAddress;

    return locationHeaderCell;
}
```

As you guys can see, I am using a prototype cell to be my header.
What I want to accomplish is to access this header in the didUpdateLocation delegate to change a label (refresh it). I do not want to use `[reload data]` because I am receiving two different responses from different web servers. One from Parse and another from Apple. Therefore I do not know which one will come first. 
I try to retrieve the header view and it prints Null.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

You could keep a reference to this `LocationHeaderCell` in a property for example:

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) LocationHeaderCell *myHeader;
```

and modify your code like this:

```
if (self.myHeader==nil)
    self.myHeader = (LocationHeaderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LocationHeaderCellIdentifier];
```

so in `didUpdateLocation` just do a `self.myHeader.lblCurrentAddress.text = @whatever";`

Comment: So I am keeping a reference and it is working. However, what I do not understand is why if I write  '(LocationHeaderCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:LocationHeaderCellIdentifier];' It brings me nil.

Comment: It brings you nil, because there is no cell that can be dequeued. dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier always provides you with an unused cell (one that is off-screen for example), if any exists. You will never get a cell that is currently being displayed on screen from this method. If you keep a reference to a limited number of cells (like for example the header cell) then it is a good practice. Visible cells are kept in memory (and are referenced) by the iOS anyway.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any other way to get the cellView? I also was trying to search through the subview of the table but it did not work.